# How to catch or handle the Quota exceeded firebase exception to avoid app crashing?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a free plan from firestore which is only 50k documents per day for the reading. My app gets 1000 documents every user which is my quota will reach fastly if I have 50 users. I knew already that to fix this problem, I need to switch my free plan to a paid plan. For now, I need to prevent my app from crashing if the quota exceeds.

When My quota exceeded, the app crash

> com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException:
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException:
>   RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Quota exceeded.

My problem is how to catch or handle the quota exception to avoid app crashing?

I tried like this

```
   try {
        db.collection("system_config")
                        .get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.getResult() != null)
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshots : task.getResult()) {
                            SystemConfigModel model = snapshots.toObject(SystemConfigModel.class);
                            SystemConfigEntity entity1 = new SystemConfigEntity(model.getYoutube_api_key());
                            roomViewModel.insert(entity1);
                            global.setSystemConfigEntity(entity1);
                        }
                }).addOnFailureListener(e -> Toast.makeText(StartUp.this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show());
}catch(Exception e) {
      Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
}
```

I am trying to handle or catch the exception by using try and catch but didn't work for me. I think try and catch is not the best way to prevent my app from crashing.

Comment: The error message indicates that you've exhausted the quota that is available. On the free plan the quota

Comment: Yes, I knew that already but my problem is when that quota reaches the limit my app crash. I want to prevent my app from crashing and display that exception to the users. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think you should use a `try/catch` there. Your `FailureListener` should be triggered when you reach your quota. I don't think your crash is coming from the `query` itself but somewhere else after you get your query and try to use the `null` `roomViewModel`

Comment: @Racu Thank you. The crashing exception is not about the query. I fixed the problem by adding `if (task.isSuccessful())` before the `if (task.getResult() != null) {}`.

Comment: @NorynBasaya Yes, I did not pay attention to the `OnCompleteListener`, you don't need to attach a `addOnFailureListener`. Use `OnCompleteListener` and `task.isSuccessful()` OR Use `OnSuccessListener` and `OnFailureListener`.
BW ;-)